# How to update a Firestore field from a pub sub function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-pubsub

I have set up a pub/sub function to fire every minute and I want to check if the current time is equal to the start time any of the Firestore entities then change a value if it is :

```
exports.updateDraftStatus = (event, context) => {
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;
  console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString());

  const db = admin.firestore();
  time = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now())
  const snap = db.collection("leagues").where("startTime", time).get()
  await Promise.all(snap.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.update({Started: 'Off'})));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.get()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Query#get) returns a `Promise<QuerySnapshot>`, and not a `QuerySnapshot`. You will need to `await` the snapshot, or use a `then()` block.

```
exports.updateDraftStatus = async (event, context) => {
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;
  console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString());

  const db = admin.firestore();
  time = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now())
  const snap = await db.collection("leagues").where("startTime", time).get()
  await Promise.all(snap.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.update({Started: 'Off'})));
};
```

or

```
exports.updateDraftStatus = (event, context) => {
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;
  console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString());

  const db = admin.firestore();
  time = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now())
  return db.collection("leagues").where("startTime", time).get().then((snap) => {
    return Promise.all(snap.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.update({Started: 'Off'})));
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks Frank I will try out this solution, I have changed it to your suggested but now I am getting an error that admin is not defined I have added admin under dependancies in the json package but still getting undefined any suggestions ?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem, related to how you import the `admin` package into `index.js`. It should look something like `const admin = require('firebase-admin');`.